# Python/Beautiful Soup - find_all limit limits results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the historical results from the Premier League but while the html gets all results, the Beautiful Soup find_all only returns 200 results (there should be 463. Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Many thanks

Matt

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.skysports.com/premier-league- 
results/1992-93"
url_content = requests.get(url).content
url_bs = BeautifulSoup(url_content,'html.parser')
match_list = 
url_bs.find_all(attrs="class":"fixres__item"})
print(len(match_list))
```

Comment: Where are you seeing all 463 results?  In a browser?  Smells like JavaScript.

Comment: I noticed that the page has a “Show More” link at the bottom to load all the results. Without a lot of research, the issue may be that you have to click the link with BS4 to have access to all results.

Comment: @Liquidgenius I don't think BS4 is capable of that.  He may have to use something like Selenium.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, I believe I used Selenium the last time I had to do something like this in conjunction with BS4.

Comment: Hi John, LiquidGenius - Yes, I can see the full 463 results in page source in a browser but as you say there are only 200 results loaded in the first instance (without clicking 'See More'). I shall research Selenium - it's not something I have used before, in truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-results/1992-93')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'plus-more__text')))

if driver.find_element_by_class_name('plus-more__text'):
    print('Found')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_class_name('plus-more__text'))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_class_name('plus-more__text'))

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

links = soup.findAll('div', class_='fixres__item')

print(len(links))


driver.quit()
```

Comment: I got 462, not 463.

Comment: Wonderful - Thank you so much for your help. As soon as the Chrome Driver finishes installing I shall give it a try.

Comment: I run headless so it’s not going to bring up a browser. @emvy03 you can just delete the code line that says headless to see the browser.

Comment: That was from your code I had weeks ago from another answer :D @ewwink

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, guys! :)